# Pandas Row Select Where String Starts With Any Item In List

Tags: pandas

I want to select a subset of rows in a pandas dataframe, based on a particular string column, where the value starts with any number of values in a list.

A small version of this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['aa10', 'aa11', 'bb13', 'cc14']})
valids = ['aa', 'bb']
```

So I want just those rows where `a` starts with `aa` or `bb` in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `startswith`

```
df.a.str.startswith(tuple(valids))
Out[191]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

After filter with original df

```
df[df.a.str.startswith(tuple(valids))]
Out[192]: 
      a
0  aa10
1  aa11
2  bb13
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your brilliant help.